# How do we execute .SQL file in snowflake? How do we execute multiple .SQL files in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Lets say I have multiple .SQL files and I want to execute in snow SQL how do we do it?

What if have have single .SQL file and I want to execute? how to do that?

Comment: Install SnowSQL CLI and use `!load` to execute scripts as `sql` files. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-use.html#:~:text=Connection%20Parameters%20Reference.-,Running%20in%20a%20Session%20(!source%20or%20!load%20Command),-To%20run%20a

Comment: hi @PhilCoulson..how do we execute multiple .sql files at a time?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `SnowSQL` installed, and you have multiple script files to run, you can create a master script file that has `!load` command for individual scripts and save that as a file

```
!load path/file1.sql
!load path/file2.sql
!load path/file3.sql
```

You can then run the master script file like below

```
!load path/master_file.sql
```